# Capacity of car radiator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The capacity of my car radiator is $24$ quarts. The mixture of antifreeze and water in the radiator was $25$%?
antifreeze.Since the winter is approaching I wanted a larger percentage of antifreeze. My mechanic suggested a $38$% mixture. I therefore needed to drain off some of the current mixture and replace it with pure antifreeze.How much of the current mixture do I need to drain off?

I set up an equation and got $4.16$ quarts. I'm just not sure if that is the correct answer and way to best solve this problem.

$x$ = amount drained by $x$ quarts

The amount remaining would be $(24-x)$ quarts.

The drained amount is replaced by $100$% anti-freeze meaning:

$$100x + 25(24-x) = 38*24$$

$$75x=24(38-25)=24*13$$

$$x= 24 * \frac{13}{75}$$

$$X=4.16 Quarts$$

let amount drained be x quarts, amount remaining = $(24-x)$ quarts
the amount drained is replaced by $100$% anti-freeze, so
$$100x + 25(24-x) = 38*24$$
$$75x = 24(38-25) = 24*13$$
$$x = 24*\frac{13}{75} $$

Comment: Please post the equation you set up. We can't suggest a "better way to solve this problem" unless you outline the way you solved the problem, including variables and equation(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your result.

Desired amount of antifreeze: $0.38(24) =9.12$ quarts.
Amount of antifreeze currently in radiator: $0.25(24) =6.0$ quarts.
Total volume of radiator: $24$ quarts.

Let $v$ equal the amount of $25\%$ mixture to drain and of pure antifreeze to add.

$$\frac{6}{24}(24-v) + v = 9.12$$

Solve for $v$ to get $v=4.16$ quarts. So drain $4.16$ quarts of the current mixture and add $4.16$ quarts of the pure antifreeze to get your desired $38\%$ mixture for the winter.

Hope this helps,

Paul Safier